# Post from AngularJS to GAE Python

Tags: python, angularjs

I am try to set up an AngularJS front end to communicate with a Python back end on GAE.  I have the following code:

```
//Angular factory
app.factory('turn', function($http, $q){
   return{  
     get : function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer()
        var url = 'save'
        $http.get(url).success(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data)
        })
        return deferred.promise
    },
    save : function(data){
        $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'save',
            data: data,
            headers:{'Content-type': 'application/json'}

        }).success(function(response){
            return response
        }).error(function(response){
            return response
        })

    }

}//close return
})//close factory

#Python back end
class Data(webapp2.RedirectHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    data = {"success": 'Yes', "payload": "You got it"}
    json.dump(data, self.response.out)

def post(self):
    logging.info(self.request.get('name'))
    data = self.request.get('payload')
    data = {'response': data}
    logging.info(data)
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    json.dump(data, self.response.out)

// Line of code which fires the process and should display the response.
$scope.message = turn.save({name:'Neil', payload: 'payload'}).response
```

The get aspect works perfectly however the Post does not work on the development server.

The message seem to be correctly formed since I get status codes of 200 and when I look at the actual message (using Chrome development tools / Network) it seems like the information is there on the Headers Request Payload and the Response.

However neither Python back end nor the Angular front end can read the data.

Update:  Have been digging deeply through webapp2 documentation and came up with this solution which looks a bit of a hack to me:

```
def post(self):
    data = self.request.POST.items()[0][0]
    data = json.loads(data)
    data = {'response': data['name']}      
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    json.dump(data, self.response.out)
```

For some reason the whole of the Post Json data from Angular comes into the Webapp2 MultiDict as a key part of the of the first tuple.  This then needs to be stripped out and run through the json library to be converted to a dictionary which I can now use.

On the Angular side made some small adjustments to the code so that controller now can process the results

Factory now reads:

```
save : function(data){
        return $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'save',
            data: data,
            headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}               
        })
    }
```

Note the change in the Content-Type.  This the preferred type for data sent to webapp2.

Controller calls with:

```
turn.save({name:'Neil', payload: 'payload'}).then(function(response){
        $scope.message=response.data.response

    })
```

This now sends the information to the back end correctly and sends a response to the front end.  Note that the actual Json data that I created and sent from the back end is at response.data.  I had to look at the whole response to find where it was being placed.

I'll leave this up since I am sure I am not the only person to have hit this problem.

Comment: Is your GAE and Angular stuff all on the same host?

Comment: Yes, it is currently only on the local server in development mode.  The requests are getting through, the problem is getting the information off the requests, it does not seem to be in the correct place.